# Issue on Setting Fill Color and Opacity in Highchart.js Spider Web

Tags: highcharts

Can you please take a look at <kbd>[This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/bY5Fu/)</kbd> and let me know why I am not able to set the Fill Color and it's opacity on Highchart Spider web. I already tried to add `fillColor: '#00FF00'` to chart's series but apparently it is not working

```
series: [{
            name: 'Allocated Budget',
            data: [43000, 19000, 60000, 35000, 17000, 10000],
            pointPlacement: 'on',
            fillColor: '#00FF00'
        }, {
            name: 'Actual Spending',
            data: [50000, 39000, 42000, 31000, 26000, 14000],
            pointPlacement: 'on',
            fillColor: '#00FF00'
        }]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because an `line` chart has no fill property. Change to `areaspline` or `area`.